# Issue adding jQuery to Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

My code is not showing any error but also is not rendering the comment form when I click the add comment link. I have inserted jQuery Rails gem.

My comment controller is:

```
  class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_post
    before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy, :update]

    def index
     @comment = @post.comments.all
    end

    def new
    @comment = @post.comments.new
    @comment.user=current_user
    respond_to do |f|
      f.js
    end

    end

    def create
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.name=current_user.name
    @comment.user=current_user
    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Comment added Successfully"
      redirect_to topic_post_path(topic_id: @topic, id: @post.id)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
    end
```

My new.js.erb file:

```
    $('#comment').append(<%=  render 'comments/new' %>);
```

In my post show I have this:

```
    <%= link_to "Add Comments", new_post_comment_path(@post.id),remote: 
   true %>
```

My comment partial is:

```
    <%= form_for [@post,@comment],remote: true do |f| %>
    <% if @comment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited from 
      being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :comment,"Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :comment %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "comment",class: "btn btn-success" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

But it's not rendering the comment form when I click the add comment link. What's the issue with my code?

Comment: What is your rails version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `j render` or `escape_javascript render` instead of normal `render` here.

**comments/new.js.erb:**

```
$('#comment').append("<%= j render 'comments/new' %>");
```